# How to emphasise that a new habit was developed?

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

How to talk about habit that was developed lately?
If I want to say that lately I have developed habit of running (using present perfect progressive) I would say:
I have been running a lot lately.

But how to rephrase this sentence if I need to add that I have got used to do it lately?
I guess sentence: I have got used to run a lot lately is not grammatically correct in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Despite the use of "to", you should not use an infinitive in this case. I believe you are looking for something like "I have got used to running a lot lately".

The "to" comes from "used to" rather than an infinitive, so you need to use a present participle.

Comment: Good answer, sounds natural. I would add that in formal contexts, the correct form would be "I have **gotten** used to running a great deal lately." I also changed "a lot" because that's pretty casual too :)

Comment: I think this is more of a dialect difference. According to Wiktionary, "have got" is southern British English, whereas "have gotten" is used in American, Canadian, Irish, Northern English, and Scottish English.